# Is LiveData widget lifecycle aware?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I have been exploring architectural components of android. I am not sure if I can use the Architectural components with widget life cycle.
I have browsed a lot but no information is available for if we can use the [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html) and other architectural components like View-Model with widget? And if yes then what is the correct way to do so ?

Comment: I'm also interested with AAC with widget. Do you find info or tutorial about this ?

Comment: Actually I am not able to find anything related to Widgets in Android Architectural components. I was wondering if we can use custom Life-cycle owner and observer with widget, but I can not see widget Life-cycle events in there.